# How to rewrite URL passed on to Symfony Router?

Tags: symfony

I know that URL rewrite is done on webserver. And that is actually what is happening.

However my app reside in subfolder, and that sub-folder is passed along.

**Question:** So how can I configure router to skipp/remove that part of url that is used for routing? Maybe some Symfony event can be used for such purpose?

Info:
Symfony 2.8
PHP 5.6
IIS 8

Comment: You can't do that without configuring the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a listener if you have to:

- Pass the Router as an argument in the service definition

  `@router`
- use a onKernelRequest with a GetResponseEvent

  `public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)`
- use the Request and Response to create a new sub request

  `// No redirect, we create a new sub request
  $subRequest = $request->duplicate([], null, [
      '_controller' => $route['controller'], 
      '_route' => $route['route']
  ]);
  $response = $this->kernel->handle(
      $subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
  $event->setResponse($response);`
- if you need a redirect:

  `$url = $this->router->generate($route['target']);
   $response = new RedirectResponse($url); 
   $event->setResponse($response);`

This is the gist of it and it is working fine for an in-house solution where the user can define a redirect for part of the application. So it should be working as well to rewrite all the paths.

HTH

~thoroc

(sorry for the bad formatting)

Comment: So Symfony allow to override request url in onKernelRequest before it reach router?

Comment: I could be wrong as I am not completely versed in SF2 internals, but if you are using "public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)" for your listener, you actually get a response that you modify. Not the most elegant solution but you get to redirect where you want.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add more details about the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use the symfony router to rewrite a part of your base url is not a good idea.

Look at the web server configuration and make a specific vhost for your app that points to the web directory, or update the default .htaccess located in the web folder of your app.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Doing that already. But my app is in subdirectory as it: `domain.com/subdirectory/XYZ` Can't figure out how to strip that subdirectory from my URL :\ So I can either globaly configure symfony to treat subdirectory as part of server url... or manually add subdirectory to every route :(

Comment: From which part of the url do you want your symfony app start ? `domain.com/{route}`  or `domain.com/XYZ/{route}`?

Comment: Second one. '/XYZ/route-name' is what IIS is providing to Symfony app. I want just '/route-name'.